# XPath Selectors : Finding any link that is a tag, href tag (mailing/pdf/link) link

Tags: jquery

Following is the jQuery & CSS code. Where I want to add the class to all the a tags but I am not getting the result. Is there any way to get all the class through jQuery code.

jQuery Code :

```
$('a[@href^="mailto:"]').addClass('mailClass');
$('a[@href$=".pdf"]').addClass('pdfClass');
$('a[@href*="xyze.com"]').addClass('mySiteClass');
```

CSS Code :

```
a.mailClass{
    color: #ff0000;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.pdfClass { color: #000090; }
a.mySiteClass {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #00ff00;
}
```

body Code :

```
<div>
    <a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.com">Test</a></br/>
    <a href="http://www.xyz.com">Test</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery are you using? The xpath style selectors were removed a long time ago in version 1.2. We now have version 1.6.2!

Remove the '@' in the selectors and all should be good.

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost correct, you just have to remove the `@`

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').addClass('mailClass'); 
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').addClass('pdfClass');
$('a[href*="xyze.com"]').addClass('mySiteClass');
```